# In c# how can we pass a string to another function

Tags: c#, .net

How to pass an string to a function in c#
I give my sample code below

```
/* using stringbuilder method */
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("object");
        Console.WriteLine("orignal string ={0}", s);
        Console.WriteLine("string length  ={0}", s.Length);
        //appending string
        s.Append(" languge");
        Console.WriteLine("after appending={0}", s);
        //inserting string
        s.Insert(7," oriented ");
        Console.WriteLine("after inserting={0}",s);
        //setting a character
        int n = s.Length;
        s[n - 1] = '!';
        Console.WriteLine("final string   ={0}", s);
        length(s);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public string length(string d)
    {
        int a = d.Length;
        return (a);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and then [edit] your question to add the details that are missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("object");
            Console.WriteLine("orignal string ={0}", s);
            Console.WriteLine("string length  ={0}", s.Length);
            //appending string
            s.Append(" languge");
            Console.WriteLine("after appending={0}", s);
            //inserting string
            s.Insert(7, " oriented ");
            Console.WriteLine("after inserting={0}", s);
            //setting a character
            int n = s.Length;
            s[n - 1] = '!';
            Console.WriteLine("final string   ={0}", s);
            length(s.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static string length(string d)
        {
            int a = d.Length;
            return (a.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u give me thhis correct code

Answer (score 1):

The function length should be also static

You can't call a non-static function from a static function (in this case main).